# Direct data import from yahoo finance to gnu R

Tags: r, import, yahoo-finance

Is there a way to import time series data directly from yahoo finance to R instead of downloading every time series? Right now I download every single time series in excel then import via read.csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out package `quantmod` e.g. function `getSymbols('MSFT',src='yahoo')`
Respectively the according vignette.

Comment: I tried but I cannot calculate any figures with it. even if I use getSymbols('F',src='yahoo',return.class='ts') 
# loads Ford as time series class ts

Comment: what you get is a `ts` object as opposed to a `data.frame` which `read.csv` will return - but `ts`is what you were asking for? take a quick look at it via e.g. `head(F)`; accessing the data e.g. via `F[ , "F.Open"]` is no big deal; a good starter for you to get acquainted with time-series in R by the way, which are normally much better suited for this type [prices, etc.] of analysis (check out `zoo`and `xts` in that respect); if you don't like it feel free to transform it to a `data.frame` via `as.data.frame(F)`

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is!!

```
aapl_2 <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/Coding/R Programming/Stock Time Series Plots/aapl.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Reverse the entries
aapl_2 <- aapl_2[rev(rownames(aapl_2)), ]

aapl_close <- aapl_2[, "Close"]

summary(aapl_close)
## Min.   1st Qu. Median   Mean   3rd Qu.  Max.
## 12.94   24.69   38.13   46.80   53.61  199.80

############################

##############################
# Using the quantmod package #
##############################
# Load the quantmod packages after installing it locally.
library(quantmod)

AAPL <- getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign=FALSE)
head(AAPL)

##########################
# Charting with quantmod #
##########################
# Adding some technical indicators on top of the original plot
chartSeries(AAPL, subset='2010::2010-04',
  theme = chartTheme('white'),
  TA = "addVo(); addBBands()")

reChart(subset='2009-01-01::2009-03-03')

chartSeries(AAPL, subset='2011::2012',
  theme = chartTheme('white'),
  TA = "addBBands(); addDEMA()")

addVo()
addDPO()

# Initial chart plot with no indicators
chartSeries(AAPL, theme = chartTheme('white'), TA = NULL)

# Custom function creation
my_indicator <- function(x) {
   return(x + 90)
}

add_my_indicator <- newTA(FUN = my_indicator, preFUN=Cl,
  legend.name = "My Fancy Indicator", on = 1)

add_my_indicator()

#########################
# Graphing wiht ggplot2 #
#########################
# Create a matrix with price and volume
df <- AAPL[, c("AAPL.Adjusted", "AAPL.Volume")]
names(df) <- c("price", "volume")
```

Comment: Also, check out this link.

https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/multi-asset-backtest-rotational-trading-strategies/